# ajaxStart() called only once but ajaxComplete() called multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to do something on the call of every AJAX request on my page.

I read [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax_Events) that

> ### ajaxStart (Global Event)
>
> This event is broadcast if an Ajax request is started and no other Ajax requests are currently running.

and

> ### ajaxComplete (Global Event)
>
> This event behaves the same as the complete event and will be triggered every time an Ajax request finishes.

This means I can only track the start of one ajax event and not each individual request?

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function () {
    var t = new Date(),
        h = t.getHours(),
        m = t.getMinutes(),
        s = t.getSeconds(),
        ms = t.getMilliseconds();
    console.log("Triggered ajaxStart handler   at " + h + ":" + m + ":" + s + ":" + ms);
});


$(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
    var t = new Date(),
        h = t.getHours(),
        m = t.getMinutes(),
        s = t.getSeconds(),
        ms = t.getMilliseconds();
    console.log("Triggered ajaxComplete handler at " + h + ":" + m + ":" + s + ":" + ms);
});
```

gives me

```
Triggered ajaxStart handler    at 11:14:33:409 
Triggered ajaxComplete handler at 11:14:33:480 
Triggered ajaxComplete handler at 11:14:33:489 
Triggered ajaxComplete handler at 11:14:33:491 
Triggered ajaxComplete handler at 11:14:33:492 
Triggered ajaxComplete handler at 11:14:33:535 
Triggered ajaxComplete handler at 11:14:33:539 
Triggered ajaxComplete handler at 11:14:33:567 
Triggered ajaxComplete handler at 11:14:33:569
```

Is there any way to log every ajax start so I can attach an even to every single ajax event?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with what you're written, my only guess is that `and no other Ajax requests are currently running.` clause is catching you out.

Comment: @Dunhamzzz My thoughts exactly. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want the [`.ajaxSend`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSend/) event, which is sent for *every* AJAX request, not just the first outstanding one.