# ajaxStop fires twice... sometimes

Tags: ajax, jquery

Based on the issue in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16381552/getting-jquery-ajaxstop-to-only-fire-once-everytime) (ajaxStop was firing twice), I wrote the following ajaxStop event.

```
var ajaxCount = 0;

$(document).ajaxStop(function () {
    ajaxCount += 1;
    console.debug('calling ajaxStop, iteration ' + ajaxCount);
    if (ajaxCount == 2) {
        $('.fieldLoading').hide();
        $('.fieldValue').show();
    }
});
```

9 times out of 10 it works exactly as expected.  The debug console shows "calling ajaxStop, iteration 1" as soon as the page loads.  Then, after everything else fires, it shows "calling ajaxStop, iteration 2".  This is what I expect.  However, about 5 or 10 percent of the time it only displays iteration 1, after everything has fired (which means no data is shown).

Comment: Curious: If you log the number of ajaxStart requests (in the same fashion, incrementing a counter), does it always match the number of ajaxStop triggers? If so, you could count ajaxStart and then change your "if (ajaxCount == 2)" to "if (ajaxStopCount == ajaxStartCount)"

Comment: Actually, I don't think that will work. But counting ajaxStart and then changing your ajaxStop to ajaxComplete and using the counter ought to work. Bit convoluted though. The important thing to note is that the ajaxStop works in batch fashion. If your calls are organized in a way that they will be executed in succession and there will ALWAYS be a static number of calls (regardless of success, failure, user intervention) than your approach should work. Otherwise, it won't be sufficiently predictable.

Comment: So I tried changing it to ajaxComplete and trackng startCount and stopCount.  The problem is that sometimes they sync up before it's all done.  For instance, they both hit 6 at the same time even though there's like 14 ajax calls.

Comment: Scratch that, I had a console error so it just happened to stop there, still working

Comment: I'll go ahead and create an answer for my comments. If it works well and nobody has better suggestions, great. If not, hopefully you'll get a good solution from someone else. =]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a queue like so:

```
var ajaxQueue = $({});

$.ajaxQueue = function (ajaxOpts) {
    // Hold the original complete function.
    var oldComplete = ajaxOpts.complete;

    // Queue our ajax request.
    ajaxQueue.queue(function (next) {
        // Create a complete callback to fire the next event in the queue.
        ajaxOpts.complete = function () {
            // Fire the original complete if it was there.
            if (oldComplete) {
                oldComplete.apply(this, arguments);
            }
            // Run the next query in the queue.
            next();
        };

        // Run the query.
        $.ajax(ajaxOpts);
    });
};
```

Now I just call all my ajax events as ajaxQueue() instead of ajax().  Then, I have a $(document).ajaxStop() that I use to finish everything up.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest adding an ajaxSend() handler to count the number of ajax requests and converting the ajaxStop() to an ajaxComplete(). Rather than performing:

```
if (ajaxCount == 2)
```

You can then do:

```
if (ajaxStopCount == ajaxStartCount)
```

Additionally, you could modify your counters to count ACTIVE requests (decrement the counter on ajaxComplete, increment it on ajaxSend (your loading dialog might disappear between requests, but will re-appear as soon as another request begins; I wouldn't image much of a delay between hiding/showing, but that depends on your code organization).

Add another handler for errors, and you should be set.

Comment: This seems to work, but ajaxStopCount always ends up 1 more than ajaxStartCount.  Like you said, I'll wait to see if someone can tell me how to fix ajaxStop().  Otherwise, I'll accept your answer in a couple days.  Thanks!

Comment: Discovered something (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15072669/ajaxstart-called-only-once-but-ajaxcomplete-called-multiple-times). Updated my answer to suggest ajaxSend rather than ajaxStart.

Comment: Seems to behave the same.  I also did confirm it is possible that it hits the same number at the same time before they're complete, so this solution isn't really perfect.

http://pastebin.com/4XcV0avk

Comment: I added some debugging to the condition and it actually fires 3 times. 
            console.debug('ajaxStopCount == ajaxStartCount');

Comment: The only definitive solution I can think of if you really want to ensure that ALL possible requests are finalized is to create a queue and insert ajax requests into that queue with a unique identifier as they are started and remove them from the queue as they complete (or error, if that isn't included in complete). When the queue is empty, you will know with certainty that every request has been called and has finished.

Comment: That's actually what I just finished doing.  Now ajaxStop works flawlessly.